# Gradle Artifactory dependencies : SNAPSHOT pattern issues

Tags: design-patterns, dependencies, gradle, snapshot, artifactory

I'm having an hard time trying to figure out how to resolve a dependency over a remote artifact in Artifactory, from a Gradle build.

This Artifact is available at :

```
http://192.168.2.130:8081/artifactory/simple/libs-snapshot-local/com/company/test/1.0-SNAPSHOT/TestArtifact-1.0-20130607.104006-2.apklib
```

My build.gradle is :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://192.168.2.130:8081/artifactory/gradle"

            credentials {
                username = "$artifactory_user"
                password = "$artifactory_password"
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
            classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '2.0.12', changing: true)
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'android'
    apply plugin: 'artifactory'
}

repositories {
    maven {

        url "http://192.168.2.130:8081/artifactory"

        credentials {
            username = "$artifactory_user"
            password = "$artifactory_password"
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'http://192.168.2.130:8081/artifactory/simple'

    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-snapshot'
            maven = true
        }
    }
}
```

On Artifactory, the repository `libs-snapshot` use the maven unique snapshot behavior and is binding to the `maven-2-default` layout which has the following configuration :

Artifact Path Pattern : `[orgPath]/[module]/[baseRev](-[folderItegRev])/[module]-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev])(-[classifier]).[ext]`

Folder Integration Revision RegExp : `SNAPSHOT`

File Integration Revision RegExp : `SNAPSHOT|(?:(?:[0-9]{8}.[0-9]{6})-(?:[0-9]+))`

So from my understanding Gradle should resolve the dependency by looking at :

```
http://192.168.2.130:8081/artifactory/simple/libs-snapshot/com/company/test/TestArtifact/1.0-SNAPSHOT/TestArtifact-1.0-xxxxxxxx.xxxxxx-x.apklib
```

but it is actually looking at :

```
http://192.168.2.130:8081/artifactory/com/company/test/TestArtifact/1.0/TestArtifact-1.0.apklib
```

So obviously it does not resolve the dependency. I also tried to use the gradle compile line generated by Artifactory but it didn't do the trick either :

```
compile(group: 'com.company.test', name: 'TestArtifact', version: '1.0-20130607.104006-2', ext: 'apklib')
```

Although I spent some times reading posts and Gradle/Artifactory documentations, I'm even more confused now that I was in the beginning... So, I got a few questions :

1) Gradle doesn't seem to be using the artifactory {} section. In fact, it is only using  the url that I declare in the repositories {} section. But when I remove the repositories {} section, it only looks for dependencies locally. Why is that? What is the proper way to declare the Artifactory repositories?

2) Will Gradle be aware of the underlying `libs-snapshot` layout? If not, does the Artifactory plugin offers a way to customize artifact search pattern (in straight Maven, not with Ivy)? Because I'm only using the free version of Artifactory thus I won't be able to edit repositories layouts.

3) Why does Artifactory generate a gradle compile line that do not seems to match the layout used by the artifact container repository?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem. were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

This a soft answer I realize, but we resolve artifacts in Artifactory using gradle and all we specify is the following:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "http://repo1:8081/artifactory/repo"
    }
}
```

It's a pretty radically different configuration structure, considering it has essentially the same details. May be worth a shot.

Comment: So you just don't use the artifactory plugin and the artifactory section{} at all?

Comment: I can't find any mention of it anywhere in our gradle files. The only instance of 'artifactory' that even grep can find is in the url. As I said, I don't have a deep answer with explanation, but I can say that our stuff is working. Obviously there are a lot of variables at play, but I wasn't even aware there was an artifactory plugin!

Comment: I should add that we are using a paid-for Artifactory, and that the release engineering team set it up for us. It's quite possible they did some configuration to make things work so simply for us.

Answer (score 2):

You have some mess with Artifactory URL declarations :)

First of all, when you use Artifactory plugin, you can skip the `repositories{}` declaration (you already declare it in the `artifactory{}` block)
In that block the contextUrl should point to Artifactory root, in your case `http://192.168.2.130:8081/artifactory` (without the `simple`).
This is well documented in [Artifactory documentation](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Working+with+Gradle).

If you prefer to use the `repositories{}` declaration, you must declare a real repository there, not a root, in your case `http://192.168.2.130:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot`
This is well documented in [Gralde documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.MavenArtifactRepository.html).

I highly recommend you the Artifactory plugin approach. Working with DSL allows you easier configuration and more powerful integration.

Comment: This is what I tried in the first time. But when removing the repositories{} declaration and only using the artifactory{} declaration, it seems Gradle only tries to resolve dependencies locally. As a matter of fact, when I run it with the --debug option it doesn't even mention a single time the contextUrl that I give. Perhaps it's an issue with my Gradle configuration...

Comment: Did anyone get any further on this one? I am encountering the same issue.

Comment: What issue are you encountering? Did you use the Artifactory plugin?